# how to select characters in a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, get

how to select characters example between spaces. By this I mean, for example, to select all the words in a sentence or numbers

In this example, I try to take every third number
I did it this way but it only takes 1 character and not a set of characters, but is not effective

```
a='4 4 4\n5 5 5\n6 6 6'
a[::3]

output
'4 5 6
```

'

I need example

```
a='10 10 10\n11 11 11\n12 12 12'
output :
'10 11 12'
```

or

```
a='100 100 100\n110 110 110\n120 120 1240 154768'
output:
100 110 1240 154768
```

My all code:

```
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
import re


f = open("demofile.txt", "r")
lines = f.readlines()
for i in list(lines):
    w = i[3:]
    w = ', '.join(w.split())
    #print(w)
    #time.sleep(1)
    y = i[2]
    y=int(y)+1
    #print(y)
    c=np.array([w])
    #print(c)
    c1 = [int(i) for i in c[0].replace(" ", "").split(",")]
    c1=np.array(c1)*-1
    c1=np.array([c1]*3)
    #print(c1)
    #change code from here
    c2=c1*10 
    c1=np.transpose(c1)
    
    d=str(c1).replace("[",'')
    d=str(d).replace("]",'')
    d=str(d).replace("-",'')
    d=str(d).replace("\n ",'\n')
    #get=re.findall(r'\w+ ', d)
    get=d[::3]
    print(get)
    #print(d)
    
    #add the two resulting arrays
    c3=(c2)+(c1)
    
    #Adding leading zeros to strings in NumPy array, ensuring 3 characters for each element
    #cmb3 = np.char.zfill(cmb3, 3)
    
    # now continue with printing your output
    a=str(c3).replace("[",'')
    a=str(a).replace("]",'')
    a=str(a).replace("\n ",'\n')
    print(*(f' {i}\n'.join(s.split() + ['']) for s, i in zip(a.splitlines(),get.split())), sep="\n") 
    #print('\n')
    #print(a)
```

It is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to get desired output.

If you want to get all words between spaces in a given string then this code would do

```
import re
string = 'sjdsi aoijsd oiajqjs9 ow so'
found = re.findall(r' \w+ ', string)
```

Comment: Do you mean  this - `re.findall(r'\w+ ', string)`?  (missing string)?

Answer (score 0):

It is not completely clear to me what you are looking for, but you can call `split()` to get rid of the `\n` and then call `set` to get the unique values.

```
a='10 10 10\n11 11 11\n12 12 12'
set(a.split())
#{'10', '11', '12'}

a='100 100 100\n110 110 110\n120 120 1240 154768'
set(a.split())
#{'1240', '110', '100', '120', '154768'}
```